# How to pass a javascript variable value to bash script

Tags: javascript, bash, shell

I have a problem at work that looks like I'll need to use both some javascript and a shell script to solve.

What I need to know is - how can I pass the value of a javascript variable to a shell script?

My particular use-case is getting the selected value from an HTML dropdown list. That's fine - I can get that value and assign it to a Javascript variable. I now just need to know how to take the next step and get that variable into a bash variable.

So, let's say I have this bit of Javascript -

```
var foo = "some text" ;
```

How do I get `"foo"` into bash?

Comment: bash on the browser computer?  or bash on the server computer?

Comment: Hi jfriend00.  Bash on the browser computer.  ( Having said that, seeing how it would be done for bash on the server could also be useful for future reference. )

Comment: As asked this question doesn't make much sense. Can you clarify what the moving pieces are here a bit? This is javascript code running on a website? That you access with your browser? What is the bash script? Where does it run? How does it relate to viewing the site?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is you can't with a regular web page.  Browser Javascript code is not allowed to effect the local computer's environment for security reasons.

This would take some sort of browser add-on the end-user installed running at higher privileges in order to set an environment variable in the local computer's environment.

Answer (score -1):

You can Uses Global Variable

```js
//base.js

   var foo;
```

And Child Js

```js
 foo="some text"
```

Must Be Load Js file Base First After Second
You can debug Statement usins

```
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, Bhadresh S  (and thanks for your reply too jfriend00). I actually have a suspicion that I may have been wrong and that the bash script will be on the *server* side, not the browser. ( It will be running remotely, not on my PC which is doing the browsing). So, given that, I'm wondering how or if this could be done on the server side?

Comment: Please Give Real Example I can Try